# Python decorator with optional callable argument

Tags: python

There are many answers here on how to detect if a python decorator is used with or without arguments. They typically look like this:

```
class MyDecorator(object):
   def __init__(self, *args):
      if len(args) == 1 and callable(args[0]):
         # no arguments
      else:
         # arguments
```

But now I have the following use-case:

```
@MyDecorator(lambda x:2*x)
def foo():
   pass
```

Which is wrongly detected as a 'no-argument' case.

Is there a way to detect this situation as well?

[edit: Added missing 'self' parameter]

Comment: Did you try to name the argument?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think that is exactly the problem: if called with one callable parameter, `@MyDecorator` thinks it doesn't get any "real" parameters and works directly as a decorator. In other cases, it worls as a decorator creator. And in the case of the lambda, it erroneously does the former instead of the latter.

Comment: @Lawnmower When are you planning to fix the `__init__` line in the question? As you suggest it once worked, it cannot have been used this way.

Comment: I've added the missing 'self'. @glglgl correctly identified the cause of the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it will remain slightly hacky. The trick is to use named arguments. Besides that there is no clean way to differentiate between the different callables.

```
class MyDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            # arguments
            print 'got %r as arguments'
        else:
            callable, = args

@MyDecorator(some_function=lambda x:2*x)
def foo():
    pass
```

Comment: That's the answer I feared. I hoped to avoid the clutter. Maybe I make the parameter mandatory. Then I don't have to make the case distinction (but end up with very confusing behaviour if one forgets the lambda).

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__` method requires a *`self`* parameter:

```
class MyDecorator(object):
   def __init__(self, *args):
      if len(args) == 1 and callable(args[0]):
         # no arguments
      else:
         # arguments
```

Without it you *always* have *one* argument at least and it will *not* be callable; it is the decorator instance instead. In other words, without an explicit `self`, `*args` will be *two* elements long when you pass in the argument and it'll be `args[1]` you wanted to test.

Comment: Ah, sorry that's just a mistake in the question's cut-down example code. Of course I have a 'self' in the real thing.

Comment: Right, then I misunderstood what you were asking; clearly Wolf did. :-)